# Karate API call errors out with http call failed after 2255 milliseconds for url post upgrade from 0.9.6 to 1.0.1

Tags: upgrade, karate

My tests were written with karate 0.9.6 and now I am in the process of fixing some of the failed tests after upgrade to 1.0.1.
I am unable to get around this one failure though

**Error as per summary html:** *****org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 3; The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""., http call failed after 2255 milliseconds for url:
at the when method GET of my API call.*****

Anyone else seen this before? Which xml file is it referring to here?

Thanks,

NT

Comment: maybe you found a bug in karate so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your requests simply failed and the server returned HTML. It can be a bug, so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Also see in case this is the reason: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1706